# Magento2, Crontab can have more than one group?

Tags: magento2, crontab

I create two cronjobs, on same Module, but they should run separeted.
On my `crontab.xml` I have:

```
<group id="price_update"> 
    <job name="price_update_cron" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Cron\PricesCron" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
<group id="stock_update"> 
    <job name="stock_update_cron" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Cron\StockCron" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Some how the first group `price_update` is running, but the second group `stock_update` is not running. 
Do anyone knows why? Can I have more that one cronjob running in a `crontbab.xml`?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Ankit Shah, thank you, but I can find the solution

Comment: Ok good. Keep it up. Do post you solution for community

Comment: Ankit Shah, sorry, my misstake, I meant, I can not find the solution